# Remove element from an array (useState) via onClick

Tags: arrays, reactjs, onclick, jscript, snackbar

I have an array that contains `<SnackBar>` elements:

```
const [snackbars,setSnackbars]=useState([
    <ReactSnackBar Show={true}>
       Snackbar 1
       <Icon onClick={snackbars.pop()}/>
    </ReactSnackBar>,
    ...
]}
```

I want to click on the `<Icon/>`, to remove this current snackbar, so that the *next* snackbar becomes visible.
But this doesn't work with the error

> ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration `snackbars' before
>   initialization

If I use a helper function inside the `onClick` it's the same.

Are there any suggestions on how to solve that?

Comment: `onClick={snackbars.pop()}` means you're assigning the return value of `snackbars.pop()` to `onClick`. What you actually want is to create a new inline function that will call `snackbars.pop()` when clicked: `onClick={() => snackbars.pop()}`

Comment: But that's just the first problem. `pop` mutates the original array, this is wrong when dealing with react state. State should be treated as immutable. Second, storing JSX directly in state is usually not a great idea. Instead store some identifier for each component and map over it in the render to get your snackbars JSX.